# CodeIgniter - Changing normal SQL into CI's own language

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Can someone show me how to change the following SQL into CI's active stuff.

```
    $query = $this->db->query('UPDATE pollanswers SET pollAnswerPoints = pollAnswerPoints + 1 WHERE pollAnswerID = '.$pollanswerid.'');
    return true;
```

Also, how would i add an if statement to that to see if it completed properly return true, if not return false?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->set('pollAnswerPoints', 'pollAnswerPoints + 1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('pollAnswerID', $pollanswerid);
$this->db->update('pollanswers');
```

Edit:

```
if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
{
     return true; 
} else 
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that ... What about the if else statement?

Comment: So it would be - if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){ return true; } else { return false; }

Comment: Or just return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0.  Wrapping in if - else is a bit redundant...